# Redirecting from one form to other form on clicking login button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a security module to my database application and what actually I am trying  to do is whenever I click on Logon button, it exits the login form and opens the main form depending on the role of user. 
I have the following code:

**LOGIN FORM:**

```
public void Login()
    {
        frmCommissionReport _commReport = new frmCommissionReport();

        if (_commission.Login(cbxLoginName, txbPassword))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
             // close this form - do not exit the application
            frmCommissionReport frm = new frmCommissionReport();
            this.Close();
            frm.ShowDialog();

        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password not recognised");

        }

    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Login();

    }
```

> **MAIN FORM (frmCommissionReport)**

```
public frmCommissionReport()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        _login.ShowDialog();

    }
```

> But for some reasons whenever I fill in the login details and click Login Button, it again opens the same Login Form and keeps on duplicating the login form whenever I click Login Button rather than redirecting me to Main Form

[image]

Comment: What's `_login` in the main form constructor?

Comment: @DGibbs It is an object for Login form

Comment: So when the main form is loaded, it shows the login form...? `But for some reasons whenever I fill in the login details and click Login Button, it again opens the same Login Form` and you're surprised by this? Try removing that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the apt solution for my problem in a bit different way than I started with

> **LOGIN FORM**

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{

    #region "Properties"

    private bool _Authenticated = false;

    public bool Authenticated
    {
        get { return _Authenticated; }
        set { _Authenticated = value; }
    }

    #endregion
 public void Login()
    {

        if (GetLoginAuthentication(cbxLoginName, txbPassword))
        {
            this.Hide();
            //MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
            Authenticated = true;
            //frmCommissionReport frm = new frmCommissionReport();
            //frm.ShowDialog();


        }
        else
        {
            Authenticated = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password not recognised");

        }

    }
```

> **MAIN FORM**

```
public frmCommissionReport()
    {
        frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
        login.ShowDialog();

        if (login.Authenticated)
        {// block of code
}
```

This worked fine without any issue

Answer (score 2):

When you login successfully, you are instantiating another frmCommissionReport(), which is in turn calling _login.ShowDialog() (I'm assuming on a new instance of Login), and this.Close() is closing the existing Login form, not the new one associated with the new frmCommissionReport() instance.

Comment: This is what I saw too when I looked over the code.  I believe you're correct, the `_login.ShowDialog();` is calling the login form to appear from the other.

Comment: @Thabo Thanks, I removed it but when I click Login, it is still not redirecting me to the Main Form

Comment: The main form is already instantiated, so use that to control other dialogs in the application, not the Login class. Take all the frmCommisionReports out of login, and put their logic in the main form. Get the return value of _login.ShowDialog and call it before InitializeComponents() so you can loop the login form or bomb out or whatever before you create components on the main form.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this.close into this.hide

```
if (_commission.Login(cbxLoginName, txbPassword))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
         // close this form - do not exit the application
        frmCommissionReport frm = new frmCommissionReport();
        this.hide();
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }
```